# Show form for specific time interval in php

Tags: php, html

I want to execute if condition only when current date and time is less than end date but it is not working. There is minor problem in my code which i'm unable to find.    How to fetch current date and time as format of  strtotime("05:15pm August 19 2016"); function so i can compare them both?

```
<?php
    $startdate  = strtotime("05:15pm August 19 2016");
    $enddate    = strtotime("05:14pm August 19 2016", $startdate);
    $current    = date("h:i M d y");**strong text**
    echo date("h:i M d y", $current);

    if ($current < $enddate) {
        echo date("M d", $startdate) . "<br>";
        echo " <strong> What do you prefer?</strong>
    <form role=\"form\" method=\"post\" action=\"VotingProcessing.php\">
        <label class=\"radio-inline\">
            <input type=\"radio\" name=\"optradio\" value=\"Breakfast\">Breakfast
        </label>
        <label class=\"radio-inline\">
            <input type=\"radio\" name=\"optradio\" value=\"Lunch\">Lunch
        </label>
        <label class=\"radio-inline disabled\">
            <input type=\"radio\" name=\"optradio\">Both
        </label>
        <input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\">
    </form>";
    $startdate = strtotime("+1 week", $startdate);
    }
    else{
        echo "Expired";
    }
```

Comment: `if( $date > $start && $date < $end ){/*show form*/} else {/*show statistics/*}` ?

Comment: Recommend trying something first and then asking the community.  A lot of folks would like to help you figure it out but don't necessarily want to do it for you.

Comment: Help me. I've posted the code above.